# "echo $?" works in linux/aix only, not in solaris/hp-ux [strange ! or i'm missing any thing ]?

Tags: bash, shell, command

if i fired "zcat1" [it's not exists anywhere] on all the platforms and immediately does echo "$?", I'm getting failure value [1] in Linux and AIX only not in HP-UX and Solaris ?
Please let me know, what is missing, I'm using sh shell everywhere ? Do i need to do any settings ?

```
uname -a
Linux xxxxx 2.6.18-164.el5 #1 SMP Tue Aug 18 15:51:48 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@xxxxx tmp_a]# which zcat1
/usr/bin/which: no zcat1 in (/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin/admincmd/:/root/bin)
[root@cllin11 tmp_a]# echo $?
1

uname -a
AIX xxxxxx 1 7 00CE6F1F4C00
[root@xxxxx /]# which zcat1
which: 0652-141 There is no zcat1 in /usr/bin /etc /usr/sbin /usr/ucb /usr/bin/X11 /sbin /usr/java5/jre/bin /usr/java5/bin /root/bin /opt/VRTSvcs/bin /opt/VRTSvxfs/cfs/bin /etc/vx/bin /opt/pware/bin /opt/VRTSvcs/bin /etc/vx/bin /opt/VRTSvxfs/cfs/bin /opt/VRTS/bin /opt/pware/bin /opt/VRTSat/bin /opt/VRTSat/bin.
[root@claix01 /]# echo $?
1

# uname -a
HP-UX xxx B.11.23 U 9000/800 3547050632 unlimited-user license
# which zcat1
no zcat1 in /usr/sbin /usr/bin /usr/ccs/bin /usr/contrib/bin /usr/contrib/Q4/bin /opt/perl/bin /opt/ipf/bin /opt/hparray/bin /opt/nettladm/bin /opt/fcms/bin /opt/ssh/bin /opt/mx/bin /opt/wbem/bin /opt/wbem/sbin /opt/resmon/bin /usr/bin/X11 /opt/sec_mgmt/bastille/bin /opt/drd/bin /opt/dsau/bin /opt/dsau/sbin /opt/firefox /opt/gnome/bin /opt/perf/bin /opt/ignite/bin /usr/contrib/kwdb/bin /opt/mozilla /var/opt/netscape/servers/shared/bin /var/opt/netscape/servers/bin /var/opt/netscape/servers/bin/slapd/server /var/opt/netscape/server7/shared/bin /var/opt/netscape/server7/bin /opt/graphics/common/bin /opt/perl_32/bin /opt/perl_64/bin /opt/prm/bin /usr/sbin/diag/contrib /opt/sfm/bin /opt/sec_mgmt/spc/bin /opt/java1.4/jre/bin /opt/spb/bin /opt/swa/bin /opt/hpsmh/bin /opt/thunderbird /opt/upgrade/bin /opt/gwlm/bin /usr/contrib/bin/X11 /sbin /home/root
# echo $?
0

uname -a
SunOS xxxxxx 5.10 Generic_141445-09 i86pc i386 i86pc
# which zcat1
no zcat1 in /usr/sbin /usr/bin /opt/VRTS/bin /var/VRTS/bin/
# echo $?
0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the [hp-ux manpages for `which`](http://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/man1/which.1.html) don't say anything about an exit status, so you shouldn't really expect one.

as alternative you could use `type`, which [is part of POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/type.html) and should be required to return an error code on failure.

Answer (score 2):

You are staring into the abyss of POSIX implementation hell ..... here is a tidbit from the "Oracle at Redwood City" to help you along:

[None shall pass the POSIX river without permission](https://blogs.oracle.com/moazam/entry/solaris_which_command_does_not)

Comment: This is not that much related with POSIX as `which` isn't defined or even mentioned by POSIX in the first place. One could argue Gnu/Linux and AIX break the BSD original implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already cover why you can not rely on the exit status of `which`. In bash, you should use the builtin `type`, which will not change depending on OS.

```
$ type -P ls
/bin/ls
$ echo $?
0
$ type -P askdjas
$ echo $?
1
```